# Strange MathJax line break behavior in mobile browsers

Tags: bug, mathjax

I was looking at [one of my answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10550/10248) on my mobile browser (Safari for iPhone 4S iOS 7.1.2, but the result is the same on any mobile browser I've tried so far), and I found a broken MathJax snippet: the mathematical expression is mixed with the text of the answer making it hard to understand its meaning.

**This happens probably because of the snippet being larger than the answer's container: the MathJax expression wraps, but the answer's text doesn't, and this causes an odd result.**

I'm adding a screenshot from my iPhone:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The bug report is also posted on [meta.se]: [Strange MathJax line break behavior in mobile browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253036). (I'm just adding link for a reference. Perhaps it helps that the people who find the post here might upvote also the other post on the network-wide meta.)